# How can I add a page indicator to this jquery div carosel I made?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I put together this quick carousel  that I'm using to cycle through different divs that contain graphs and other various data. I would like to have something indicating which "page" or div you are currently viewing.

Here is an example of what I'm currently doing to iterate through the divs. 
http://jsfiddle.net/d6nZP/64/

My plan is to have a row of dots that have either a active or none active state depending on which page is indicated in the row. But even a basic page counter would work at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is a simple pager for your carousel, enjoy it ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/d6nZP/65/

Comment: That's great man thanks! Quick question though is there a way I would be able to append images to use as counters rather than numbers?

Comment: I'm envious of your speed, thanks again for the help! I'm guessing to handle active states I could use an If state to check and see which page is currently displayed and switch to an active based on that.

Comment: Yes, but I recommend you use a plugin like jQuery Cycle, is the most simple and easy way to make a carousel in jquery. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Yea I have seen that but I figured If I try on my own first its a better learning experience, not to mention it doesn't seem like they offer any form of pagination with the plug in.

Answer (score 2):

Created something you can use http://jsfiddle.net/BadBoyBill/8yHmy/

```
    $("div[id^=marquee]:gt(0)").hide();

    function startTimer(){
        i = setInterval(rotate, 2000);
        return i;
    }

    var intID = startTimer();

    function stopTimer(){
        clearInterval(intID);
    }

    function rotate(){
        reference = $("div[id^=marquee]:visible").hide().next("div[id^=marquee]");
        reference.length ? $(reference).fadeIn() : $("div[id^=marquee]:first").fadeIn() ;
        dot = $(".indicator-on[id^=indicator]").removeClass("indicator-on").next("a[id^=indicator]").addClass("indicator-on");
        dot.length ? $(dot).addClass("indicator-on") : $("a[id^=indicator]:first").addClass("indicator-on");
    }

    $("div[id^=marquee]").each(function(){
        $("#indicators").append("<a href='#' id='indicator' class='indicator'></a>");
        $(".indicator:first").addClass("indicator-on");
    });

    $("a[id^=indicator]").click(function(e){
        var index = $("a[id^=indicator]").index(this);
        //alert(index);
        $("div[id=marquee]").hide();
        $("div[id=marquee]").eq(index).show();
        $("a[id=indicator]").removeClass("indicator-on");
        $("a[id=indicator]").eq(index).addClass("indicator-on");
        stopTimer();
        intID = startTimer();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("a[id=indicator], div[id=marquee]").mouseenter(function(){
        stopTimer();
        //alert("mouseenter");
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        stopTimer();
        intID = startTimer();
        //alert("mouseexit");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to put something in the content divs themselves that acts as a counter, i.e. in the first div put "1/3", in the next "2/3", etc. That method, of course, would have the disadvantage of not being very responsive to change. A better option is to keep a separate variable that keeps track of which element is visible, then when the "next" button is clicked, the variable is incremented, then a check is run to see if that index exists. If not, you loop back the beginning. The opposite, of course, with the previous button.

Comment: Yea I really want to avoid using a static number in the divs themselves since the number of divs will be variable. I figured I could some how count the total number of divs and set that to variable and then display proper number of dot images based off that variable first as a starting point. I'm still a jquery noob though.